# calling int variable from another view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

CatsTableViewController.h

```
@interface CatsTableViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSMutableArray *categoriesArray;
  int catInt;
}
@property int catInt;
@end
```

I have synthesized it in my `CatsTableViewController.m` and I have `#import "CatsTableViewController.h"` in the view that I want to call this int in (`CodesTableViewController.m`).

Detailed Info:

This int is keeping track of which array to load into `CodesTableViewController.m`'s `TableView`. An if statement helps the app determine which array count to use at `numberOfRowsInSection` and at which array to use at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

So I beleive the question to ask is how do I call this variable from another `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to consider using `NSUserDefaults` to store this `int` value.

The [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has all the information to get you started. In addition to the wealth of information there, here's a simple example of how to save and retrieve an `int` (this works as well for `float`, `BOOL`, `NSString`, `NSDate`, `NSData`, `NSArray`):

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(int)myInt
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setInt:myInt forKey:@"catInt"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}

-(int)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int val = 0;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults intForKey:@"catInt"];

    return val;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using NSUserDefaults to pass the variable.  `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:catNum forKey:@"catNum"];
    [defaults synchronize];` That sets the var to be passed. And this retrieves it: `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *catNum = [defaults objectForKey:@"catNum"];
    catNumLocal = catNum; ` Thanks for putting me on the right pathg.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reference to instance of class `CatsTableViewController`, for example, named `catsController` then you could just call:

```
int localCatInt = [catsController catInt]; // your array index
```

Comment: I'm really not sure how to make a reference to an instance of the class CatsTableViewController.  I tried "CatsTableViewController *catsController = [[CatsTableViewController alloc] init];  but that didnt seem to help me .

Comment: I don't know relationships between `CatsTableViewController` and `CodesTableViewController` so I couldn't help you here